# Grails Spring security core pre-logout

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails Spring Security Core plugin and I need to perform a few actions when logout happens such as delete some class instances related to the user. I tried the following code:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

class LogoutController {

def index = {
    def currentUser = currentUser()
    currentUser.searchedResults.each{searched->
        def searchInstance = Search.get(searched.searchId)
        searchInstance.delete()
    }
    redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
}

private currentUser(){
    return User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
}
}
```

However Grails is giving the error: *No such property: User for class: LogoutController* 
My guess is that this is happening because when I installed Spring security core plugin, the LogoutController and LoginController were created in a different package called "default package". Is there any way to overcome this issue? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Where is your `User` class located (i.e. what package)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to import the User class. Something like:

```
import mypackage.User
```